# Selenium + Chromedriver : unable to retrieve result from a PerformanceObserver object

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, performance-testing, web-testing

I try to call a Selenium executeScript function though Chromedriver (v 77.0.3865.40) where I want to retrieve a PerformanceObserver object.

In JS, next I have initialized the driver, called a web page with success, I launch the following code:

```
let result = await driver.executeScript(
        "const r = function() {"+
        "let lcp;"+
        "const po = new PerformanceObserver((eList) => {"+
        "const e = eList.getEntries();"+
        "const last = e[e.length - 1];"+
        "lcp = last.renderTime || last.loadTime;"+
        "});"+
        "po.observe({type: 'largest-contentful-paint', buffered: true});"+
        "return lcp;};"+
        "return r();"
        );
    console.log("LCP : ",result);
```

But the result is always null

Is there an issue in my function call ? or a current limitation in Chromedriver ?

Thanks for support.

Comment: You would definitely need executeAsyncScript if you want to return lcp from the callback. Also it seems like you should really be using puppeteer for this, it would be much easier.

Comment: Same issue using puppeteer evaluate command : console.log(await page.evaluate(() => {
     let lcp;
            const po = new PerformanceObserver((eList) => {
             const e = eList.getEntries();
             const last = e[e.length - 1];
             lcp = last.renderTime || last.loadTime;
            });
            po.observe({type: 'largest-contentful-paint', buffered: true});
            return lcp;}
            ));

Comment: Using executeAsyncScript you would do `arguments[0](lcp)` in the callback. arguments[0] is the callback that returns the lcp oblect to the script context.

Comment: The solution with arguments[0](lcp) works perfectly. Thanks !

Comment: ok, that's great:)